# svn ignore file-content seemed to be ignored :(

Tags: svn

I'm administaring three SLES-servers with a vufind-project that had been running under svn. The servers are: a catalog-web-server, an index-server and a test-server.

Last week vufind-project on the catalog- and index-server were upgraded to a new development-level by copying-over of the complete vufind-folder from the test-server and doing some server-specific configuration-changes afterwards. 
Sadly, this was done outside of svn, resulting in a less than happy svn-database on the catalog- and index-server...

Thus far, I've done these steps to get a working svn-environment based on the current vufind-project-folders of the catalog- and index-server up and running:
- deleted the old repository
- created a new repository with the same name as the old (so that we can still use all configurations we've set up for using Tortoise-SVN via PCs later when everything is working again)
- imported the complete current folder (/usr/local/vufind) into the repository
- checked out a new working copy into a different directory (/_kate/local/vufind)

It seems that the new working copy doesn't suffer from any of the problems that the original current folder has (like revision numbers that were way too high etc.), 
but now I've got **all** files and folders of the vufind-project revisioned, so I really need to unrevision a lot of them.

Following the advice I found here

http://superchlorine.com/2013/08/getting-svn-to-ignore-files-and-directories/

I made my own ignore-file called _svn-ing which looks like this

```
cache
compile
covers
index
logs
spellShingle
spellchecker
*.log
*.mrc
*.tmp
customRules.bin
java_fixes.csh
man_import.sh
```

and called it up from the /_kate/local/vufind-folder with this command-line:

```
svn propset svn:ignore --recursive --file _svn-ign . > svn-ignore-ausgabe.txt 2>&
```

Contrary to my expectations not only the files and folders listed in the files got property 'svn:ignore' set on but every file and folder in the vufind-folder.

If it were helpful I could post the content of the file svn-ignore-ausgabe.txt but I didn't want to put 291 lines without asking first. But perhaps someone here has an idea already were my error lies.

Thanks
Kate

Answer (score 0):

It not clear what was the first step which 'broke' the working copy you have, however I guess that you should use [vendor branching strategy](https://vufind.org/wiki/subversion#vendor_branching) to avoid such issues in future. (I may be wrong here because I don't understand those steps that you describe as *"resulting in a less than happy svn-database"*).

As of `svn:ignore` property, it [affects unversioned items in your working copy only](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html):

> Subversion's support for ignorable file patterns extends only to the
>   one-time process of adding unversioned files and directories to
>   version control. **Once an object is under Subversion's control, the
>   ignore pattern mechanisms no longer apply to it**. In other words, don't
>   expect Subversion to avoid committing changes you've made to a
>   versioned file simply because that file's name matches an ignore
>   pattern—Subversion always notices all of its versioned objects.

You have to set `svn:ignore` or `svn:global-ignores` (requires SVN 1.8+ client) before you add your project's items to Subversion repository. I.e. the workflow should be as follows:

1. `svn checkout` a working copy of a repository path where you plan to put your project's items,
2. In the working copy, run `svn propset svn:ignore --recursive --file _svn-ign . > svn-ignore-ausgabe.txt 2>&`,
3. Use `svn add` to your project's items to version-control. You'll notice that items that match the ignore pattern from `svn:ignore` are not added.
4. `svn commit` new revision to the repository.

Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/)!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer from slightly different side

I can't translate

> not only the files and folders listed in the files got property 'svn:ignore' set on but every file and folder in the vufind-folder

into anything understandable (you can re-phrase it in German), because

- content of file for `-F` option define, **what** content to write, not **not where**
- `svn:ignore` is property of directory (define ignore-pattern for content of *this folder*), have not sense as property of file (and I never got `svn:ignore` for file)
- `-R` (`--recursive`) of propset, as expected, define `svn:ignore` for current folder and **all nested folders** at the full deep - and only for folders

In my test case `ps` for the root of repo

```
>svn propset svn:ignore --recursive --file ignore.txt .
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'trunk'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'branches'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'branches\FullHTML'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'tags'
```

but all files are still untouched

```
>svn st -v
 M               5        5 lazybadger   .
 M               5        2 lazybadger   branches
 M               5        2 lazybadger   branches\FullHTML
                 5        2 lazybadger   branches\FullHTML\natasha_i_budushee.html
                 5        2 lazybadger   readme.textile
 M               5        1 www-data     tags
 M               5        5 lazybadger   trunk
                 5        5 lazybadger   trunk\G1.txt
                 5        2 lazybadger   trunk\G10.txt
...
```

If vufind dir with subdirs have 291 nodes, then svn-ignore-ausgabe.txt with 291 strings is correct result, you can forget about it.

But your work is still unfinished - as @bahrep mentined, svn:ignore affect only unversioned items (i.e new objects, which appear in WC and match patterns, will not be added to repo without explicit naming or doesn't screw up output of `svn st`), but already versioned files and folders you have to remove from by hand, but still save this objects in Working Copy `svn rm --keep-local ...`. In order do not repeat all removes by hand, you can use `_svn-ign` one more time: as source for rm paths: read about `--target` option for svn rm and try something like

```
svn rm --keep-local cache --target _svn-ign
```